# Android db.delete does not work properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to ask for some help about delete() in android.
In my program, I try to delete all records in table before I insert any new data. When the button "Import data" was first pressed, the records can be inserted normally. However, if the button was pressed again without re-installing the app, errors will be find in LogCat.

Here is the error found:

**Logcat Error :**

```
07-03 10:46:19.829: D/ice(25736): Path of csv folder get in modile
07-03 10:46:20.809: D/ice(25736): Name of csv was get and change into string
07-03 10:46:22.389: D/ice(25736): Csv column sucessfully read
07-03 10:46:25.399: D/ice(25736): Read next record
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736): Error inserting tran_code=NS order_qty                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  =2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  item_code=IC559 line_no=1 customer_ref_no="PO# 29051925" order_date=20140702 cust_code=094659
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: columns order_date, cust_code, item_code, tran_code are not unique (code 19)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at com.iceapp.ImportCsvActivity$2.onClick(ImportCsvActivity.java:197)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-03 10:46:27.669: E/SQLiteDatabase(25736):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I believe that the above error was due to inserting multiple records with same primary key.

I did not receive any errors or messages during executing the delete statement. Can anyone help me to figure out why the delete statements does not work properly???

**Java code:**

```
button_import_csv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            Log.d("ice","database opened");
            db.delete(tableName[1], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[2], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[3], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[4], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[5], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[6], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[7], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[8], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[9], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[10], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[11], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[12], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[13], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[14], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[15], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[16], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[17], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[18], null, null );
            db.delete(tableName[19], null, null );

            Log.d("ice","old data existed in database was all cleared");
            try{
                File csvpath = new File("/sdcard/downloadedfolder/"+route_folder);
                Log.d("ice","Path of csv folder get in modile");
                File[] csvfile = csvpath.listFiles();
                //get all csv files' name and store it as array
                Log.d("ice","Name of csv was get and change into string");
                //Put all name of csv into a string array

                FileReader file = new FileReader(csvfile[0]);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                String line = buffer.readLine();            //read first line to get the column
                Log.d("ice","Csv column sucessfully read");
                String[] cols = line.split("\t");           
                db.beginTransaction();
                for(int j=0;j<24;j++){
                    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.d("ice","Read next record");
                        //read every single line of record in csv
                        String[] str = line.split("\t");
                        for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                            contentValues.put(cols[i], str[i]);
                        }
                        db.insert(tableName[j], null, contentValues);   
                    }
                }
                buffer.close();
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();
            }catch (IOException e){

            }

            helper.close();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is this `tablename[1]`?

Comment: Do you not want to delete contents from tablename[0] ? Looks like there is a conflict because your table is already having contents.

Comment: Thank you, Siva and Varun. I should delete records starting from tablename[0]. The above error seems solved but i still need to do more testing on it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the tablename[1],if you want to delete all the records,then change it to this:

```
                  db.delete(tablename,null,null);
```

this should work because when you put the selection arguments to null it deletes all of the table's entries.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to know why tablename[1] is different from tablename as both of them are strings.

Comment: table name is a name of an SQL table not a String

Comment: Opss, sorry. My meaning is the name of table in string format.